# What shutdown timers with/without GUI are there available?

Tags: software-recommendation, shutdown, time

What shutdown timers with/without GUI are there available?

- any type of action possible? shutdown hibernate etc but also custom command?
- how to set time? time to go or at specific timestamp?
- integration with desktop environment - progress bar to specified time
- warning before action - possibility to prolong/adjust/cancel?
- keep default setting, eg 1 hour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of shutdown timers available on Launchpad that look interesting.

[Easyshutdown](https://launchpad.net/easyshutdown) - simply shuts down your PC

[image]

[ComplexShutdown](https://launchpad.net/complexshutdown) - it has much more options such as hibernate/suspend etc.

[image]

Comment: thanks, own/smaller screenshots would have sufficed :) unity2d integration doesnt seem to be that close yet

Answer (score 3):

The simplest one would be [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29), and it can be used to schedule any command.

Answer (score 1):

[Shutdown GTimer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shutdown-gtimer/files/)

[image: Shutdown GTimer]

Answer (score 1):

as BigStack said, using crontab is a very easy/non install way to do it.

As a tutorial [here](http://digitography.co.uk/digitographyblog/?p=500) suggests:

If you open terminal you can type

```
sudo gedit /etc/crontab
```

this will open your systems crontab file in gedit.

you can then add this line to it:

```
00  22   *    *   *   root   poweroff
```

where 00 is the minutes, 22 is the hours, and the *s mean every day (you can see more info on this in the [link](http://digitography.co.uk/digitographyblog/?p=500)). root says which user is to execute the command, and poweroff is the command to run.

I've done this and it works perfectly in Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: type `sudo shutdown -h <MINS>` into console...

e.g. for one hour:

`sudo shutdown -h 60`

Answer (score 0):

Crontab: Its's easy to setup a cron job for poweroff

Comment: Can you explain how, including an example crontab line?

Answer (score 0):

I know on a Mac you can use a crontab. Here are the steps. I did get it to work, but on my new system I have had some problems, you can try it. You need to do this in the terminal.

Type

```
sudo crontab -e
```

You'll need to enter your login password and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You'll now be in a text editor (vim). Carefully input the following keystrokes.

Press `i` once (this will allow you to enter text)
Let's say you want the machine to shutdown at 2am every day, we'd now enter:

```
* 2 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

If you wanted the machine to shutdown at 2:30am every day, you'd enter:

```
30 2 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

When you've typed this in, press <kbd>esc</kbd>
Then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (that's uppercase "z" twice, to write the changes and quit the editor).

You should now be dropped back to the command line where you started.

You're done!

Answer (score 0):

[SGTimer](https://launchpad.net/~georgdh/+archive/ubuntu/gdh/+packages) has a variety of options and is actively maintained on Launchpad.

[image]

**Figure 1: Main interface on Ubuntu 15.10**