# recurring scheduled shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

If I type

```bsh
sudo shutdown -h 21:30
```

at, say, 21:20, then I will get a message saying

```bsh
Shutdown scheduled for Tue 2020-05-26 21:30:00 BST, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
```

This is great. But is there a way to schedule a shutdown for *each day* at 21:30, without having to type in `sudo shutdown -h 21:30` each day?

Info on my machine (in case it's necessary):

```bsh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You are looking for `cron`

`cron` is the general purpose utility (that comes with Ubuntu) to schedule running any command of your choice at some regular intervals. The `cron` is configured and controlled via `crontab`. Understanding how to use `crontab will take some time. Before we go any further see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto for how to use crontab.

## Use `crontoab` to Schedule `shutdow` Every Night at 21:30

We want to run the script with administrator privileges. So we use `sudo` before `crontab`.. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This command will open the crontab file for the root user if one exists, or create a blank new file. Add the following line at the end of the file:

```
30 21 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h
```

Each line in `crontab` has five time-and-date fields, followed by a command, followed by a newline character ('\n'). The fields are separated by spaces. The five time-and-date fields cannot contain spaces. The five time-and-date fields are as follows:

1. minute (0-59),
2. hour (0-23, 0 = midnight),
3. day (1-31),
4. month (1-12),
5. weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday).

Therefore, `30 21 * * *` means at 21:30 everyday.

If you use `nano` as the text file editor (the default), exit the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. The editor will prompt you to save the changes. Press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the default file name.

Note we need to specify the path of the program we call via cron, in this case `shutdown`. Second, we don't need to specify the time as an argument to the `shutdown` command, as the command will be executed at that time every day by `cron`.

## Other solutions

Similar questions have been asked and answered before:

[How can I shutdown the system every day at a specific time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809484/how-can-i-shutdown-the-system-every-day-at-a-specific-time)

[What shutdown timers with/without GUI are there available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44793/what-shutdown-timers-with-without-gui-are-there-available)

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow.  Brilliant edit.  That is going in my bookmarks.

Comment: @walttheboss Thanks for suggesting the initial edit.